# Error "ImportError: Loaded module flask.testing not found in sys.modules" while testing flask app in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, nose

I am using nose and nose-gae for testing flask app in App engine. I using virtualenv.

Test case looks like this:

```
import os
import unittest
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

from tickapp import app 

class DemoTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.app = app.test_client()
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        self.testbed.init_all_stubs()

    def teardown(self):

        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def test_home_page(self):

        result = self.app.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(result.status, "200 OK")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running tests using: nosetests -v --with-gae tests

Test case files reside under 'tests' directory.

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raj/gae_projects/tick/tests/test_users.py", line 13, in setUp
    self.app = app.test_client()
  File "/home/raj/gae_projects/tick/flask/app.py", line 781, in test_client
    from flask.testing import FlaskClient as cls
ImportError: Loaded module flask.testing not found in sys.modules
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When a module is imported, it should be stored in `sys.modules` under the key `module.__name__`. Maybe a custom importer forgot to do this. What is in `sys.meta_path` and `sys.path_hooks`?

Comment: sys.meta_path is [] and sys.path_hooks has [<type 'zipimport.zipimporter'>]

Comment: I ended up using WebTest. Replaced 'self.app = app.test_client()' by 'self.app = webtest.TestApp(app). It worked!. But I still appreciate if someone solves actual problem, I am not able to figure it out.